# how do I send a POST request with x-www-form-urlencodded body? in php

Tags: php, api, postman

What I am trying to do is send a POST request with php just like this one! [image: just like this one]
and also add an authorization 'Bearer key' to be exact. finally read the JSON response.
Tried multiple suggestion but to no avail

Comment: Use PHP's `curl` functions.

Comment: In Postman there is a button at the right "Code". Press that and choose PHP curl